# What is the origin of the fungal spores?

Tags: alien-covenant

When the crew in *Alien: Covenant*

> initially land on the planet to investigate the signal, two crew
>  members are exposed to fungal spores, which eventually lead to their
>  deaths.
>  
>  [image: Fungal spores]

If the bio weapon is a creation of the Engineers, then where have these spores come from?

Are these a stage of Davids experimentation with the bio weapon?

I can only assume that this is linked to the eventual Aliens egg phase, and their activation by being disturbed.

Comment: I don't have any links or evidence of it.  but when you watch Prometheus, the black goo affects everything it combines with.  David brought the ship with this black goo to this planet, and so I just assumed these spores were when a plant came in contact with the goo.   think of the worms in Prometheus that transformed.  so similar to that